# PyTorch with GPU is not working but working fine with CPU

Tags: pytorch, gpu

My codes were working fine before but suddenly they stop working, without any error or warning.
this is the setting they were working fine.

[image]

After that, I have tried multiple options below

[image]

My current settings are in 1 env:

```
torch                 1.10.0+cu113
torch-cluster         1.5.9
torch-geometric       2.0.1
torch-scatter         2.0.9
torch-sparse          0.6.12
torch-spline-conv     1.2.1
torchaudio            0.10.0+cu113
torchvision           0.11.1+cu113
```

but nothing worked. Even I asked my server admin to create a new account for me. he created a new account and I just installed the below packages. These are the total packages installed in my conda env.
installation by

```
 pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html


Package           Version
----------------- ------------
certifi           2021.10.8
numpy             1.21.4
Pillow            8.4.0
pip               21.2.2
setuptools        58.0.4
torch             1.9.0+cu111
torchaudio        0.9.0
torchvision       0.10.0+cu111
typing_extensions 4.0.1
wheel             0.37.0
```

Here are the results: My code is always stuck here.

[image]

What could be a possible reason?, while my labmate with same setting and same server executed the same code on his user profile, it was ok.

**Further Details:**

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
>>> True

torch.cuda.current_device()
>>> 0

torch.cuda.device(0)
>>> <torch.cuda.device at 0x7fb4e8baa650>

torch.cuda.device_count()
>>> 4

torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
>>> 'GeForce RTX 3090'
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy paste them into your question and put them in code formatting.

Comment: How did you install pytorch?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, this is how i installed it. (From official website) pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html 

I update my question

Comment: DO any other cuda devices work (since you have four available)

Comment: 0 is stuck, i tried with cuda:1, it said out of memory. 2 and 3 are working but slower than cpu. 

so what was the problem. kindly guide me to some reading. i wasted 3 days on this

Answer (score 0):

I have the same type of problems, but with RTX 3060. I think the problem is the torch version.

Using torch == 1.11.0, I can move tensors to GPU, but with pastest versions can't do this.

```
Torch Geometric don't use torch=1.11.0 at the time I'm writing. 
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 with CUDA capability sm_86 is not compatible with the current PyTorch installation.
The current PyTorch install supports CUDA capabilities sm_37 sm_50 sm_60 sm_70.
If you want to use the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 GPU with PyTorch, please check the instructions at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
```